# Can a Filipino go outside the airport and travel on my own during a layover in Incheon airport without a visa?

Tags: visas, south-korea, filipino-citizens, stopovers

If ever I passed through immigration in Incheon (with Filipino citizenship, US tourist visa and LA as my final destination) and my choice of free transit tour is not available or full already, can I commute there on my own instead?

Answer (score 2):

You can only pass through immigration and thus exit the airport if you can get a visum.
Since the Philippines is not on this list:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_South_Korea
You need to apply for a visum in advance.

Some airports have these "free city tours" for these tours you do not clear immigration and thus does not require a visum.

The fact that you hold a visum for the US does not make a difference for South Korea.

Comment: Hi. Based on my experience, you only need to pass through the immigration (even without prior visa but with connecting flight), once you are granted, you can go on your own or join the super cheap transit tours. The transit tour desk is literally just near the exit so I guess you can leave on your own. I suggest joining the tours but make sure you'll always be prompt in returning to the tour bus or else you'll be left behind. Hope this will help others in the future!